# Can't get the gyroscope to work in an IOS browser by using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ios

So basically I'm trying to alter the perspective of an image by using the gyroscope in a smartphone/tablet. So far I've got most working, on anything but IOS (classic developer issue).

https://jsfiddle.net/seiftie/db020Lxk/34/

**NOTE: This can only be viewed from a device with a gyroscope. If it works, you'll see a status (ex: DeviceOrientationEvent activated).**

So for some reason this block doesn't work on IOS browsers:

```
if (window.DeviceOrientationEvent) {
   window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', doDeviceOrientation);
} 

var doDeviceOrientation =  function(event){
  // THIS NEVER GETS TRIGGERED IN IOS
  debug("Inside the doDeviceOrientation function after eventListener");
  status("DeviceOrientationEvent activated");

  sendCoords(event.alpha, event.beta, event.gamma);
  distortImage(event.alpha, event.beta, event.gamma);
}
```

I don't seem to understand what I'm missing here. If my question caused confusion, let me know in the comments below and I'll try to clarify.